# Python Menu Creation ValueError and not in list

Tags: python

How can i do a while loop to incorporate ValueError and input not in list.

```
def region():
    print("What is the Region?")
    print("1: Central")
    print("2: North")
    print("3: North-East")
    print("4: East")
    print("5: West")
    region = int(input("Region: "))
    while region not in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        print("Invalid Response. Please choose the correct region.")
        print("Please choose again!")
        region = int(input("Region: "))
```

this code will keep looping if input is not within the list of options but if i were to input characters or symbols it will raise ValueError.

Answer (score 1):

```
def region():
    print("What is the Region?")
    print("1: Central")
    print("2: North")
    print("3: North-East")
    print("4: East")
    print("5: West")
    reg = int(input("Region: "))
    while reg not in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        try:
            print("Invalid Response. Please choose the correct region.")
            print("Please choose again!")
            reg = int(input("Region: "))
        except Exception as e:
            continue
    return reg
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    r()
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test test.py", line 28, in r
    reg = int(input("Region: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'


Im still having this error

Comment: I think you also have to put the first `reg = int(input("Region: "))` in your try/except.
Then you can delete it in the try block after those two print statements